# Незачем / не за чем

Tags: орфография

Правда, что оба предложения правильны, но значения – неодинаковы?

`Мне оттудова незачем бежать.` (Нет смысла.)

`Мне оттудова не за чем бежать.` (Нет вещонки, за которой я бы-с таки побежал.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, оба варианта правильные:

(1) *А мне там нравится. Мне оттудова ***незачем*** бежать.* (Нет смысла.)

(2) *В этот магазин?  Мне туда ***не за чем*** бежать.* (Нет вещи,за которой стоит бежать).